# How to have multiple instances in singleton class?

Tags: ios, swift, singleton

There is a class declared as singleton in Swift. An instance called A is declared inside this singleton class.

Originally, there is only one instance of this A in memory.
Is there any way to make multiple instances of this A instance in a singleton class?

**A class**

```
protocol ADelegate{
    func onSuccess()
    func onFail()
}

// I want to create multiple instances of this
class A{
    var delegate: ADelegate!
    // ...
    func requestCallback(){
        //...
        // success response 
        delegate.onSuccess()
    }
}
```

```
class ModuleA: ADelegate{
    var aInstance = A(delegate: self)
    func req(){
        aInstance.requestCallback()
    }

    func onSuccess(){
        // ModuleA do something
    }

    func onFail(){
    
    }
}

class ModuleB: ADelegate{
    var aInstance = A(delegate: self)
    // ModuleB do something
}
```

**singleton class(Main)**

```
class Main{
    static var shared = Main()
    // Using ModuleA, ModuleB

}
```

Comment: Please add some code. What do you mean by "multiple instances of this A instance"? You can only have one instance (or maybe a pointer to an existing instance). Do you mean multiple instances of type A? A singleton can have multiple instances of a class (as long is the class is not a singleton itself).

Comment: "Do you mean multiple instances of type A?" -> yes. Is there no way in singleton?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make multiple instances of class A in memory then it is will not be called as singleton class. This will contradict the design pattern concept of singleton. If you want multiple instance of A then make the class as normal class. But singleton class can have only one instance.